# Optimization for C isMigrated function

Tags: c, performance

```
char* Migrated[]={"026","109"};

int isMigrated(char* codeB)
{   
    int i;
    int n=sizeof(Migrated)/sizeof(*Migrated);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   
        if(strcmp(Migrated[i],codeB)==0)
            return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

is this function optimised from execution time perspective ?

Migrated should contain at maximum 200 value all of them are 4 byte .

Comment: You should use a hash table.

Comment: If there are only two items in `Migrated` array they yes, it is optimized, but if there are thousands of items then there are better ways to code it.

Comment: Actually, if there are only two items in the array it would be better to check for the first character in `codeB` and based on it compare the string with only one viable item in the array.

Comment: Get a profiler and find out.

Comment: Dialecticus: Actually `strcmp` will scan through characters, and if the first one does not match, it will stop immediately.

Comment: Dunno -- what compiler optimization option did you use?

Comment: @Kip9000 - For *two elements*??  Any decent compiler will unroll the loop and have it done before you've figured your first hash value.

Comment: The key to optimising is usually to *not optimise* unless you have empirical evidence that it is necessary.  In saying that, understanding the complexity and memory consumption of various types of containers is very worthwhile.  For instance, the using a hash-table here with 2 items is a massive overhead.

Comment: In some embedded systems, testing against 0 is marginally faster than testing against a constant, so reverse the `for` loop: `for(i=n; --i >= 0; )`

Comment: Migrated should contain at maximum 200 value all of them are 4 byte .

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how far you intend to expand `Migrated`, but something like this could be an optimisation:

```
char* Migrated[]={"026","109"};

int isMigrated(char* codeB)
{   
    int i;
    // since we know that all strings in Migrated are 4 bytes long
    int32_t _codeB_as_int32 = *(int32_t *)codeB; 
    int32_t * Migrated_as_int32 = Migrated;

    for(i=0;
        i<sizeof(Migrated)/sizeof(*Migrated); // sizeof is a compile time constant, better to put it here
        i++)
    {   
        if(codeB == Migrated_as_int32[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

it all really depends on what you intend to have in `Migrated`.

Comment: Right now `Migrated` is an array of pointers, so this won't work. You need to redefine it as an array of 4 character arrays. Also, you should probably make sure `codeB` is 4 bytes long before converting it to an integer.

Comment: Don't do this. The compiler will do this for for itself. You just need to write the code such that the compiler can see that that's a valid thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could assert that any code has to come from the `Migrated` array and thus only compare the  addresses, i.e. omit the `strcmp` call and just test for `Migrated[i] == codeB`.

Comment: THe more assumptions you make, the better it gets.  If we assume all of the strings are 3 characters long - so 4 with terminating NULL, they be compared as `int`s - and possibly stored in this way too.  Probably not practical solution though.

Comment: @Marko: Sure, and if you assume that no given string matches, you could return `-1` right away. ;-) You have to draw a line somewhere. I just picked a more or less random assumption to illustrate that the best potential for optimization is by considering the domain of values fed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

If `Migrated` is a unchanging list that really is as short as you show then you should just hard-code the strings into the code (or use a macro, or declare them `const` (make sure they're const pointers as well as pointers to const)). That way the compiler can optimise the `strcmp` calls away to almost nothing; short strings like you show might even be done via a numeric comparison (a four byte string is the same length as a number), but don't do it manually - let the compiler sort that out. The key point is that the compiler cannot optimize this to the maximum if it can't prove that `Migrated` is constant.

If `Migrated` is unchanging, but much larger than shown, then you should use "perfect hashing". There is a tool called `gperf` that, given a list of names, will generate C code to do the lookup in an optimal way.

If `Migrated` can change at run-time and is small then you're probably just about optimal already.

If `Migrated` can change at run-time, but can be very large then a hash table is the best option. Failing that a sorted, balanced tree would be better than a list.

Comment: Does perfect hashing do better than, say, a trie table or an Aho-Corsack automaton for matching a string against other strings?  The constant factor of a hash function can be quite high (sometimes linear in the length of the string).

Comment: @sfstewman: Given [this input](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=ccache.git;a=blob;f=confitems.gperf;h=ae48d2b4b9724de975eb22fbc03d57182410481e;hb=HEAD), `gperf` produces [this output](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=ccache.git;a=blob;f=confitems_lookup.c;h=d5d1c22a2ee18c527937b779b12549dc912d3668;hb=HEAD). There's not too much computational complexity there.

Comment: @sfstewman: perfect hashing is for finding one word in a moderate sized dictionary. It's not for finding dictionary words in a corpus of text, like Aho-Corsack seems to be. Trie tables can outperform imperfect hashing, but only in the worst case, and can never outperform a perfect hash table.